Is it beneficial to store module and submodule paths in the database for dynamic routing in CodeIgniter 4?
I am building a dynamic web application using CodeIgniter 4 (CI4), and I want to avoid hardcoding routes and controllers. I am considering storing module and submodule paths in the database (e.g., modules/admin/userManagement, modules/admin/hrm, etc.) to make routing dynamic.
Here are my concerns:

Dynamic Route Management: I would like to load routes and controllers
dynamically based on the paths stored in the database. This would
allow me to easily add, remove, or modify modules/submodules without
changing the code.

Complexity: If the number of modules grows to 20+ with submodules,
could querying the database for routes on every request negatively
impact performance?

Scalability: Will this approach help scale the application in the
long term as more modules and submodules are added, or will it
introduce unnecessary complexity?

Best Practices: What are the best practices for implementing dynamic
routing in CI4, and how can I optimize the performance of dynamic
routes?


I would appreciate any advice or suggestions on whether this approach is a good idea, and how to implement it efficiently in CI4.
